# Terrible performance getting image from camera with intent

Tags: java, android, performance, android-intent, android-camera

I'm using the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` intent to allow users of my app to take a photo. I then get that photo and save it so that I can display it in an `ImageView` in the app.

The code works but the performance is awful. Once the user takes a picture the camera app lets them confirm by pressing a checkmark. Once this is pressed the screen stays for a few seconds then goes black for 5-8 seconds before eventually returning to my app.

As I said the code works, it's just incredibly slow. Any ideas on how I can improve it of where the bottleneck is?

```
public void onImageViewClicked (View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(getTempFile(this)) ); 
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}

private File getTempFile(Context context){
    final File path = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), context.getPackageName() );
    if(!path.exists()){
       path.mkdir();
    }
    return new File(path, "image.tmp");
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch(requestCode){
          case 1:
            final File file = getTempFile(this);
            try {
              Bitmap captureBmp = Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), Uri.fromFile(file) );
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(captureBmp);
            savePicture("before", captureBmp, getApplicationContext());
          imageView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
          break;
       }
    }
}

private void savePicture(String filename, Bitmap b, Context ctx){
    try {
        ObjectOutputStream oos;
        FileOutputStream out;
        out = ctx.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, oos);

        oos.close();
        oos.notifyAll();
        out.notifyAll();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private Bitmap loadPicture(String filename, Bitmap b){

    try {
        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(filename);
        ObjectInputStream ois = null;
        try {
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        } catch (StreamCorruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ois);
        try {
            ois.close();
            fis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(b);
  if (b == null) {
    imageView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
  }
    return b;

}
```

Comment: It is possible that you are doing too much work on the main thread. That's why the screen is going black. You might want to off load the reading/writing of images to a background thread using AsyncTask or a Runnable and register this through an ExecutorService. With AsyncTask you can display a progressbar to the user so they know what is happening.

Comment: @Sun Good idea! So in onActivityResult I should display a progresss indicator and run my other code in the background?

Comment: with out looking at more code, cannot say where it would be the best place. But it looks like a good place too me and you can always re-factor if need be.

Comment: Let me know if this solves the problem, I'll make an accepted answer:). If not, I'll try and help again.

Comment: @Sun no problem, I will

Comment: Man you don't need a progress indicator to take a picture. It's going to be about 1 second. And you don't need to manually open streams, etc. Just use [BitmapFactory.decodeFile](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile%28java.lang.String,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options%29)

Comment: Give BitmapFactory.decodeFile as Mister Smith suggested, it's much faster. I forgot about this!

Comment: @Sun running the code using AsyncTask definitely helped. Mister Smith  what code would I replace to use BitmapFactory.decodeFile?

Comment: you can use the actual file location, inputsteam. Have a look at the docs. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile(java.lang.String)

Comment: on the face of it, there is no need to re-compress the photo. Simple copy the **image.tmp** to your preferred location will be much faster. But maybe you can varying destinations to the capture intent, and use the files in-place

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem ? If yes, please share the solution.